# Excel Form not working

Tags: forms, vba, excel

I am a complete novice when it comes to Excel VBA Forms and tried to create the below form. I am now trying to get it to work with my pupil spreadsheet but it's not working.

[image: Form Layout]

I have got this far with the script and the only bit that seems to work in selecting the pupils name, nothing else is doing what I'd expect it to and I don't know where I'm going wrong.

[image]

This is for the schools Art Department so they can select a pupil from the list, and the Pupil Code and Pupil Form fields should be filled. They should then be able to add the number of any items bought by the pupil next to the relevant field and this should then update the relevant field in the Excel Spreadsheet. If there was an exiting number in that field it would need to add it to the number.

Any help or advice on this would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: Can you post your code up?

Comment: Just wondering if you have Microsoft Access. Doing this in MS Access is very simple in comparison.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the actual code, not a screenshot of the editor. Also please narrow down on the specific issue. See [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `RANGE` function to achieve that.

For example, if your spreadsheet looks like this:

```
+------------+--------+------------+---------------+---------------+
| Pupil Code | Pencil | Edding Pen | A5 Spiral Pad | A6 Spiral Pad |
+------------+--------+------------+---------------+---------------+
| 10154      | 0      | 1          | 0             | 2             |
+------------+--------+------------+---------------+---------------+
| 10155      | 1      | 1          | 0             | 1             |
+------------+--------+------------+---------------+---------------+
| 10156      | 0      | 0          | 0             | 1             |
+------------+--------+------------+---------------+---------------+
```

You could use the `RANGE` function to locate your pupil code in the spreadsheet by doing:

```
Dim r as Range

For each r in Range("A2:A100")
   If r.Value = textboxPupilCode.Value Then
      textboxPencil.Value = r.Offset(0,1).Value
   End If
Next r
```

The `OFFSET` function refers to a cell, seen from the current range. In this case, the cell to the right of the regarding pupil code.